# How to Bind one post object Type with other postobject Type in Advanced Custom field

Tags: plugin-development, customization, advanced-custom-fields

In advanced custom field i have two custom field i.e.product and brand . product and brand are custom post types. in product it shows all product post through custom field and brand also it shows all brand post through custom field.But i want filter which shows filter product associating with brand. for example when i select brand -> samsung it will show all products of samsung in advanced custom field.
Please if anyone have solution, please provide me.

Comment: But it is related to wordpress plugin customization.